# How to get history of asset with block hash in hyperledger fabric using node sdk

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have  assets whose state get updated  and I want get history of that asset with previous_hash and current Block_hash. I am using CouchDB as State DB of Hyperledger Fabric.

I tried fabcar example function `'getHistoryForAsset'` but it can give me only `TxID` but I need Block hash with this.

Can anybody help me how can we do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the transaction ID you can call (evaluate) the **GetBlockByTxID** transaction function on the system **qscc** chaincode to get the block that contained that transaction. It expects a transaction ID as an argument and returns a **common.Block** protobuf response payload.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos/blob/f44816d6f621f1f7615cb4fc65643791eb6d8ce6/common/common.proto#L142

Note that a block only contains the hash of the previous block, not the hash of itself.